# Is there any way to remove scrollbar arrows in IE11 with pure CSS in 2019? (No JavaScript)

Tags: css, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

Is there any way to remove scrollbar arrows in IE11 with pure CSS in 2019?

IE11 seems to have some options to customize the scrollbar, but it seems like there is no way at all to hide the arrows. Asking this question to make sure.

Here is a fiddle (launch in IE11 to see) https://jsfiddle.net/0u2a1zco/1/

I've added these random styles, but obsiously they won't remove the arrows:

```
 body{
  scrollbar-base-color: green;
  scrollbar-face-color: black;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: blue;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: yellow;
  scrollbar-track-color: grey;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: orange;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: brown;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: cyan;
}
```

*FYI I'm not looking for a custom scrollbar library that uses JS. All of them are supported by small teams and have a lot of bugs.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It is not possible to get rid of the scrollbars as far as i know.

My solution was to set the body fixed:

```
body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems no appropriate method using pure CSS to meet your requirement.

I've also tried those plugins and as you've said it may have some issues.

But I have a workaround to hide the whole scrollbars.

We could not only hide the arrows but could hide the scrollbar.

You could just add:

```
    body {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
    }
```